# Printing JTable in landscape mode according to JTable width

Tags: java, swing, printing

Im developing and application in which one of my task is to print `JTable` in landscape mode with readable text size (i.e 14 / 16). Now Im succeeded in to make it readable text size but cannot be able to change its orientation.

Here is my snippet of code for printing.

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("TESTING");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("PAGE # {0}");

tableName.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 18));
tableName.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,header,footer);
```

I know it'll not change its orientation, please tell me how to change its orienation.

Comment: what do you mean 'print' a `JFrame`

Comment: i meant to print its content (populated values), but issue is just to change its orientation.

Comment: but why `JFrame`? I think you mean `JTable`... can you post a picture of what you mean?

Comment: oh Sorry, you are right " Jtable "

Comment: But what exactly are you trying? are you trying to have **text** print vertically or have the table look differently...

Comment: I have a Jtable populated some values, I want to print it in landscape mode with readable font size

Comment: Have you looked at `PrinterJob`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the orientation when your already trying to print the page. If you need to provide page with different orientations, you will want to look at the [Pageable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html#PageFormat()) interfaces for more detailed information.